# NoMethodError: undefined method `refund_request' for #<PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::Payment>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

`rails 4.2.6`
`ruby 2.3.1`

I am using the Ruby PayPal SDK and have successfully created a payment and saved the payment_id. I am receiving the following error when trying to issue a refund.

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'refund_request' for #<PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::Payment>`

```
  def self.refund_successful?(payment_id)
    require 'paypal-sdk-rest'
    include PayPal::SDK::REST
    include PayPal::SDK::Core::Logging
    PayPal::SDK::REST.set_config(
      :mode => "sandbox", # "sandbox" or "live"
      :client_id => ENV["paypal_client_id"],
      :client_secret => ENV["paypal_client_secret"])
    payment = Payment.find(payment_id)
    refund = payment.refund_request # <= Error occurs here.
    refund = payment.refund_request({}) # <= Also tried this.
    if refund.success?
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

I have not added any params to the `refund_request` method since the amount refunded is the "Full" amount and not "Partial". Although, just for testing purposes I added the `amount` and still received the same error.

This is what I am following from PayPal:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/blob/master/samples/sale/refund.rb

Answer (score 0):

Is this an method within a class? If so, keep in mind that when you define methods using `self.method_name`, it is treated as a class constant and can not be called on instantiated classes.

For example

```
class HelloWorld
  def self.foo
    puts "Hello World!"
  end

  def bar
    puts "Hello World!"
  end
end
```

The method `foo` could only be called in the following manner

```
HelloWorld.foo
```

And the method `bar` could only be called by first instantiating the class and then calling the method. For example,

```
hello_world = HelloWorld.new
hello_world.bar
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but I am actually calling the method like so: `Payment.refund_successful?(transaction_id)`. Everything works properly and the PayPal payment obj is created on `payment = Payment.find(payment_id)`. The problem arises when the `refund_request` is called.